# Grails asset pipeline does not work seem to work for importing less files

Tags: grails, less, asset-pipeline

I am working with a Grails project that uses the Asset Pipeline. I have the following 1 css file and 2 less files...

### main.css

```
/*
*= require flex/xBrowserFlex.css
*= require dashboard/dashboard.css
*/
```

### xBrowserFlex.less

```
.simple-column-flex{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

### my.less

```
@import "xBrowserFlex.less";
```

But when I try to access the page I get the following error in my grails console...

```
2015-02-16 11:04:08 ERROR [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver] MissingMethodException occurred when processing request: [GET] /mxnetweb/assets/lineplanning.css
No signature of method: org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined.replaceAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, asset.pipeline.processors.CssProcessor$_process_closure1) values: [url\([\'\"]?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\./\@\#\?\ \&\+\%\=]+)[\'\"]?\), ...]. Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined.replaceAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, asset.pipeline.processors.CssProcessor$_process_closure1) values: [url\([\'\"]?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\./\@\#\?\ \&\+\%\=]+)[\'\"]?\), ...]
    at asset.pipeline.processors.CssProcessor.process(CssProcessor.groovy:35)
```

So this looks like it might be an issue with the asset pipeline. How do I handle this?

*Asset Pipeline Info*

```
<grails.assets.less.version>1.9.0</grails.assets.less.version>
```

*Update*

To clarify, if I comment out the include and just copy the less into the my.less file everything works fine. The problem here is that it doesn't work when I try to import another less file that is included in the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to remove the

```
*= require flex/xBrowserFlex.css
```

and make sure the `xBrowserFlex.less` file was in the same folder as `my.less`.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really provided enough information to figure out what's causing the problem e.g. the file referred to in the error message is `lineplanning.css`, but you haven't mentioned this at all.

Perhaps you can figure out where you're going wrong by comparing your project to [this example](https://github.com/domurtag/festivals), which uses the `asset-pipeline` plugin with less and CSS.

[style.less](https://github.com/domurtag/festivals/blob/master/grails-app/assets/stylesheets/style.less) imports various other less files, and the CSS generated from `style.less` is included in [this file](https://github.com/domurtag/festivals/blob/master/grails-app/assets/stylesheets/default.css) via

```
/*
*= encoding UTF-8
*= require autocomplete/styles.css
*= require style.css
*/
```

Notice that we `require style.css`, because that's the name of the output file produced from `style.less`.

Comment: Sorry lineplanning.css == main.css. You might be right, it may be because the file that is doing the require is CSS and not less. Let me check that out.

Comment: Wow that is a pretty awesome project.